# Options to learn in Ruby besides IRB and FXRI

Tags: ruby, windows, irb

I Was wondering if anyone had some suggestions to quickly test their coding lines in windows. Right now, I am currently using repl.it

I used to use fxri, but it doesn't work in later versions and I feel that irb lacks a lot of the useful tools that fxri has (example:built in, easily accessible library with descriptions of commands)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you don't know how to use a debugger then learn. Too many people rely on using `puts` to figure out what their code is doing, but a debugger drops you into the middle of your code, allowing you to check variables, jump to different places, check the variable's contents there, then run or stop at other places. It's like being inside your code once you've used it for a while. You'll need to install a debugger for your version of Ruby, but it's a very worthy tool to learn. I can't imagine not having it in my toolbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Pry](http://pryrepl.org) tool is a great learning resource. You can view source code and documentation on demand, and trivially explore a library or program using an intuitive file system metaphor.